# Creation of the b2c-extensions-app by script

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

When you create a ADB2C Tenant Resource, an application registration is also created, named `b2c-extensions-app. Do not modify. Used by AADB2C for storing user data`. This is a special application which is needed for crud operations.

Around the internet and in the docs, it is mentioned that it gets created automatically, but that's not the case. It is created only after you login into that tenant and go to app registrations, it is a trigger of some sorts. How do I know this? I reached to Microsoft support.

My question: this interferes with some of my automation scripts. Does anyone know of an endpoint to which I can make a rest request so this app gets created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, after a lot and I mean a lot of trial and error, I finally found the endpoint that causes the creation of that app. I will show a code snippet in PowerShell.

```
$context = Connect-AzAccount ...

# Aquire an access token from the resource: https://management.core.windows.net/
$tokenItem = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate(
        $context.Account,
        $context.Environment,
        $TenantId,
        $null,
        'Never',
        $null,
        'https://management.core.windows.net/')

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://main.b2cadmin.ext.azure.com/api/tenants/GetAndInitializeTenantPolicy?tenantId=<your_tenant_name>&skipInitialization=false" `
-Method "GET" `
-Headers @{
   "Authorization"          = "Bearer $($tokenItem.AccessToken)";
   "x-ms-client-request-id" = ([guid]::NewGuid().Guid)
}
```

Comment: I deleted my answer. But when I tried your solution, it shows `Invoke-WebRequest : An error has occurred.Unauthenticated` although I have got a valid access token for `https://management.core.windows.net/`. Can you tell me how you get the token?

Comment: I use auth code flow in Postman to get the access token. I also tried use `$accessToken = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://management.core.windows.net/").Token` in powershell. Neither of the 2 tokens work.

Comment: Maybe I missed an add permission operation in app registration? Can you show it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, I added a snippet of how I'm acquiring the `accessToken`. Make sure that in the URL you write the name of the tenant, no the id. The name is of form: `foo.onmicrosoft.com`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I successfully creates the b2c extension app. It's cool!

Comment: Np! The automation of the tenat is really annoying. Probably in the summer I will make a powershell module available in ps gallery

Comment: Thanks for this solution! Just to add for those who don't want (or can't) use Azure PowerShell - an alternative method of getting the access token would be with Azure CLI like this: `az account get-access-token --tenant $B2CTenantId --query accessToken -o tsv` - .

Comment: Is x-ms-client-request-id a required parameter?

Comment: I don't remember exactly, try with and without it and see what happens